# I am stuck on "Currency" level in Aqueduct for iPhone

Tags: aqueduct

Been trying to crack this level for several days now but for the life of me just can't.
Can't seem to find a walk through so I'm asking here.
It's the 2nd puzzle on the last "Super hard" level and it's called "Currency".

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck for days on this one.  You only need to use five pieces. (The three t-bars, the elbow piece and the other three section piece)